# Can social networks run JavaScript when indexing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-crawler, single-page-application

For a few years, Google crawlers can run JavaScript in `SPA` websites in order to index the content of the website. But social networks (like Twitter, Facebook, et cetera) do not.

Incidentally I saw [this](https://ionicthemes.com/product/login4-ionic-login-component) website that uses `AngularJS` (version 1.x, so there is no Angular universal). It uses routing and all meta tags are like this (you can see the others in the page source):

```
<title>{{$meta.title}}</title>
```

But social networks are able to render them (tested in Twitter and Telegram messenger).

Any idea how this is possible? Do social networks run JavaScript?

Comment: You're correct in your observation. What you need to do is to identify the social network user agent and make sure that you show it a rendered version of the page, or any simplified structure with the Open Graph tags  (But only for **social networks crawlers**  NOT to GoogleBot)

Comment: @AlonEitan How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, social networks still don't run javascript in SPA pages.

You can make a simple test to simulate Facebook's crawler and check what the site you linked does under the hood. It looks like the page returns another response when the `User-Agent` connects with one of the social crawlers (e.g. `facebookexternalhit/1.1` for Facebook).

You can check it by yourself by running the following command in your terminal:

```
curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" <page address>
```

The page you linked returns a result that looks like it renders on the server side:

**Response for Chrome User-Agent:**

```
[...]
<meta name="description" content="{{$meta.description}}">
[...]
```

**Response for Facebook Crawler User-Agent:**

```
[...]
<meta name="description" content="Login4 is a beautiful Login component for your Ionic app. This template contains Intro, Walkthrough, Login and Sign up screens.">
[...]
```

Even if Angular 1.x does not support server-side rendering there is another method - render the page using a real browser, save the HTML output and make a "cached" version for the crawlers. If the HTTP server recognizes crawler's User-Agent, it sends as a response a file from another directory.

Comment: Very nice description. Thanks. I tested by curl. For facebook crawler it renders and shows the result. Is there any tutorial for doing this? Or what you mentioned at the end of your answer?

Comment: @vahidnajafi I've been doing stuff like this before, so I can provide you some documentation and write about configuring the server and making it automatically :)

Comment: I would appreciate it if it's possible. What can I do?

Comment: @vahidnajafi Today in a free time I will send you all the needed information :)

Comment: Here is my email address: vahid[dot]vdn[at]gmail.com